# Is using CALayer to display CGPaths affect performance in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, calayer

I am drawing some lines, curves and ellipsis using CGPath in iOS. I wanted to animate the rendering of the lines and curves.

Lets say I want to animate 25 curves in the view. Is using CALayer to animate the curves the best solution available?

Will it be burden on the memory if 25 layers are created to display 25 lines.  I assume drawing plainly using bezier paths with methods like fill and stroke consumes less memory than using CAlayer.

Comment: Why don't you measure the performance yourself? Animating 25 paths on screen shouldn't take you to long to test.

Comment: I can also do that..I too think it will have an impact for sure..I thought I can get this info if someone has experience of testing it..Thanks I understand I could it myself..

Comment: "Is using CALayer to animate the curves" How are you planning to animate the curves? I can think of more than one way that uses CALayers to do that

Comment: I am planning to  use CAShapeLayer and animating it using CABasicAnimation..Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: There are but you should probably start with a basic animation.

Comment: ok Thanks..I am thinking that without using CALayers or its derivatives the animation of path drawing like Lines, Curves are not possible..is my understanding correct?

Comment: It's possible but less pleasant ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28306/discussion-between-krishnan-and-david-ronnqvist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It became apparent from the chat that the OP wants to animate the paths as if they were drawn, not necessary animate how the path changes.

I recommend reading [Animating the drawing of a CGPath with CAShapeLayer by Ole Begemann](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/) which explains how to do this. In short, animate the `strokeEnd` property of the shape layer.

---

From the chat:

> **A:** When you say "I wanted to animate the rendering of the lines and curves" do you mean drawing them as if someone drew them with a pen?
>   oleb.net/blog/2010/12/…
>
> **Q:** ok thanks David.. I wanted it in someway similar to the link you have posted..
>
> **A:** The second one?
>
> **Q:** yes the second one..I wanted the curves to be animated from the beginning position to end position..Thanks for your kindness.